# File Location when File is created after invoking function from JMX console

Tags: java, file, file-io, jboss, jmx

I have created a function which is getting called from the JMX console.When a user clicks on button in JMX console the function is called and the data is being copied to a file using the code:-

```
try
{
String date=ClassDemo.getDateAndTime();
String FileName="Information"+dateAndTime;
BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(strFileName));           
StringBuffer sb=new StringBuffer();
sb.append("\n");
sb.append("some work");
out.write(sb.toString());
out.close();
}catch(Exception e)
{
e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Since the code is not throwing any kind of exception I am assuming the function is doing what its meant to do and the file is also being created.However I am not able to find the location of the file.

Can anyone let me know where the file will be formed.

The application is deployed on JBoss5.0

Answer (score 0):

You can just print the path to file in your function. Something like this:

```
try
{
String date=ClassDemo.getDateAndTime();
String FileName="Information"+dateAndTime;
File file = new File(FileName);
System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath());
BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));           
StringBuffer sb=new StringBuffer();
sb.append("\n");
sb.append("some work");
out.write(sb.toString());
out.close();
}catch(Exception e)
{
e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: I found the easier way of doing the same.Create a file in the same place where I was creating the original file using File file=new File(); Then print the absolute path to that file.This path will be the same where my old file is getting stored.Hence I was able to trace it....Anyway thanks for your answer.